# Enable to display many digits on clicked button on the screen of my reactjs calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calculator

i don't know why when i click on DigitButton the calculator disappeare like there is a bug. I know the problem is on the curerentOperation property side but I actually  don't know which problem it is. When i remove the currentOperation and previousOperator in the backticks each digit is rendered.

here is the [link](https://codepen.io/Brefix/pen/jOpBarm)`to my Pen`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post the code in your question, don't link to any random external page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer you need to get access to `previousOperation` using `state.previousOperation`

```js
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        previousOperation: `${""}${payload.digit}`,
        currentOperation: `${""}${payload.digit}`
      };
    case ACTIONS.CLEAN:
      return {};
    case ACTIONS.ADD_OPERATOR:
      return {
        ...state,
        // Line: 43
        previousOperation: `${state.previousOperation || ""}${payload.operator}`
      };
  }
};
```